# Insl and outsl gives "Matching constraint does not allow a register" error

Tags: linux, gcc, xv6

So here's the code in XV6 source code (x86.h):

```
static inline void
outsl(int port, void* addr, int cnt)
{
  asm volatile("cld; rep outsl" :
  "=S" (addr), "=c" (cnt) :
  "d" (port), "0" (addr), "1" (cnt) :
  "cc");
}

static inline void
insl(int port, void* addr, int cnt)
{
  asm volatile("cld; rep insl" :
  "=D" (addr), "=c" (cnt) :
  "d" (port), "0" (addr), "1" (cnt) :
  "memory", "cc");
}
```

It gives this error:

```
kernel/x86.h:7:3: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
    7 |   "cc");
      |   ^~~~
kernel/x86.h:4:3: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
    4 |   asm volatile("cld; rep outsl" :
      |   ^~~
kernel/sound.c:53:1: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
   53 | }
      | ^
kernel/sound.c:53:1: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
kernel/sound.c:53:1: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
kernel/sound.c:53:1: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
kernel/sound.c:53:1: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
kernel/sound.c:53:1: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
kernel/sound.c: In function ‘read_pci_config’:
kernel/sound.c:17:3: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
   17 |   outsl(0xcf8, &tmp, 1);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
kernel/sound.c:17:3: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
kernel/sound.c:17:3: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
kernel/sound.c:53:1: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
   53 | }
      | ^
kernel/sound.c:53:1: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
kernel/sound.c:53:1: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
kernel/sound.c:13:6: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
   13 | uint read_pci_config(uchar bus, uchar slot, uchar func, uchar offset)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
kernel/sound.c:13:6: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
kernel/sound.c:13:6: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
kernel/sound.c:13:6: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
In file included from kernel/sound.c:10:
kernel/x86.h:4:3: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
    4 |   asm volatile("cld; rep outsl" :
      |   ^~~
kernel/x86.h:4:3: error: output number 0 not directly addressable
kernel/x86.h:4:3: error: matching constraint does not allow a register [-Werror]
kernel/x86.h:4:3: error: asm operand 3 probably doesn’t match constraints [-Werror]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [<builtin>: kernel/sound.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone had any idea what's the cause of such error?
FYI I'm using the code from older XV6 versions in the latest XV6 version (2021.9). I tried using the original io.h which also has the 2 functions, but it gives the same error.

Comment: I tried reproducing this error message in godbolt, but had no luck.  What's your target platform?  x86?  x64?  Looking at some other questions about this error message, perhaps you could try: `asm volatile("cld; rep outsl" : "+S" (addr), "+c" (cnt) : "d" (port) : "cc");`?

Comment: [Works fine here](https://godbolt.org/z/jPW115sz7).  What compiler are you using?  What version?  What compilation flags?

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm using the Makefile provided in [MIT XV6](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/riscv/Makefile).

Comment: Oh, you are building the [RISC-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC-V) version of xv6.  So it seems that you are taking inline asm from the x86 version and trying to use it in the RISC-V version, and naturally that isn't going to work; they have totally different instruction sets.  What is your actual goal with all this?

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm trying to initialize Intel AC97 sound card, like how it's done [here](https://github.com/THSS13/XV6/blob/master/xv6/sound.c) for an older Xv6 version.

Comment: Well, that driver is totally x86-centric - port-mapped I/O throughout.  I don't think RISC-V even has such a thing as port-mapped I/O - it's all memory-mapped.  Do you genuinely have a RISC-V device with an AC97 sound card (or emulation thereof)?  If you want to support the card you will probably have to largely rewrite the driver.  Or is it that you really want to just run on x86(-64) devices, and you have mixed it up with the RISC-V version by mistake?

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm just using a QEMU emulator. The purpose of all this is to write an audio player in the xv6 OS. Does this mean I have to use another sound card instead?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude with this question, but I am not sure if we are on the same page at all.  Do you understand that x86 and RISC-V are entirely separate CPU architectures?  https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/ isn't merely an update of https://github.com/THSS13/XV6/, it's a port to a completely different hardware architecture.  You cannot reasonably expect to take machine-specific code from one to the other.

Comment: @NateEldredge I get it now, thanks for your help.